# aws - is it possible to use Cognito user pool custom field in lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have created a custom field "permissions" in my user pool.
[image]
[image]

I wonder if it is possible to use this field in my lambda function, so that I can do some permission control for calling the corresponding lambda function.

For example

```
if((**custom.permissions**).includes("admin")){
   // execute the lambda function
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you are using serverless and proxy lambda integration, you can set your lambda with [cognito authorizer](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers ), and your attributes in `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims['custom:permissions']`.

Answer (score 1):

For example if your lambda function was written using python boto3 you can get the user Attributes like this:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

response = client.get_user(
    AccessToken='string'
)
```

The response structure contains
UserAttributes (list) --
An array of name-value pairs representing user attributes.

For custom attributes, you must prepend the custom: prefix to the attribute name.